# Using .container in navbar shrinks in extra small display

Tags: bootstrap-4

The bootstrap v4-alpha documentation shows that [you can use `.container` inside the navbar to have a centered (non-fluid) content](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#containers).

However, this seems to not work correctly on extra small displays, as the `.container` box shrinks too small, and thus the logo and the menu button get stacked on each other.

Here's [a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/L09pmazc/) that shows the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in alpha 6 [there is a bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21848) that makes a `container` inside the navbar shrink width on small screen. This will be fixed in beta, but until then you just need a little CSS to keep the inner container full width on mobile.

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```